# LinkedIn Javascript SDK Fail To Return Positions

Tags: javascript, sdk, linkedin-api

I am trying to use LinkedIn Javascript SDK to retrieve some information including positions fields. I copied the code from the internet but it seems something is not working quite right because the code i copied doesn't return positions fields as supposed to be. I tried on ApiGee it worked fine and it returned the list of positions as i am expected. If you look at the code below , do you think i missed something or the javascript SDK itself has some buggy problems ?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js">
api_key: yourapikey
authorize: true
onLoad: onLoad
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function onLoad() { 
    IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
}

// Handle the successful return from the API call
function onSuccess(data) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(data));
}

// Handle an error response from the API call
function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

// Use the API call wrapper to share content on LinkedIn

function getProfileData() {
    //alert(IN.ENV.auth.oauth_token);
    IN.API.Raw("/people/~:(id,positions)?format=json").result(onSuccess).error(onError);
}
</script>
```

Return result is showing this :

```
{"id":"wQplQQjzLa","positions":{"_total":0}}
```

Comment: I think it is just a typo. You have a space in your URL, right in `"/people /...`, remove that space and it should work.

Comment: I remove the space but still returning the same result.

Comment: I had hosted the code on : http://test.dirtoilgas.com/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello there @John Hadikusumo,
Well, I do understand that this reply would be happening only a year later but, I too was facing some problems with the linkedin api integration especially when it came to the "positions" object values.

Apparently when I got an error, what it meant was that the user who is using his linkedin profile to authorize, that particular user has not initiated his experience details and thus has no value;

To circumvent this particular problem here is what I had done which had helped me:

```
    function onLinkedInLoad() {
        IN.Event.on(IN, "auth", getProfileData);
    }

    function onSuccess(data) {
        console.log(data);
    }

    function onError(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }

    function getProfileData(){
        IN.API.Profile("me").fields(["firstName","lastName", "email-address", "positions"]).result(function(data) {
            var profileData = data.values[0];
            var profileFName = profileData.firstName;
            var profileLName = profileData.lastName;

            //this is the piece of code that helped me out;
            //might work for you as well;
            if(data.values[0].positions._total == "0" || data.values[0].positions._total == 0 || data.values[0].positions._total == undefined) {
                console.log("Error on position details");
                var profileCName = "Details Are Undefined";
            }
        else {
            var profileCName = profileData.positions.values["0"].company.name;
        }
        var profileEName = profileData.emailAddress;

        //and other logic/code continues...
    });
}
```

So I do hope this helps you out. Do let me know if you had faced any other errors, I could use some help in case I would need to improve my existing code.

Cheers and Have a nice day.